# How to convert Java date to Google Graph API's date format?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp

I am getting dates from my mysql database to be used in the Google Graph API. However both of the formats are fairly different.

The format which I gotten from MYSQL is something like this `Sat Dec 12 00:00:00 MYT 2015`

Whereas, Google Graph API is like this :

```
new Date(2012, 10, 01, 00, 58, 00, 00)
```

How can I use the date I got from my database to be used in Google Graph API ?

Below is my sample code but not working:
Java code:

```
String sDate = "2015-12-12";
            Date dDate = format.parse(sDate);
            System.out.println(dDate); //Sat Dec 12 00:00:00 MYT 2015
```

My Javascript code:

```
var date = "<%=dDate%>";
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Closing Price');

          data.addRows([
            [date, 9.12],  [date1, 1.59]
          ]);
```

I am coding all these in JSP.